# How to use textures and arrays in CUDA?

Tags: arrays, cuda, textures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read back a CUDA Texture for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353622/how-to-read-back-a-cuda-texture-for-testing)

Steps for using textures and arrays in CUDA?